# Set up a scheduler that triggers every 10 minutes in C# ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to set up a scheduler that will trigger every 10 minutes, activating a database query. I can't find any good tutorials on this and some advice would be great. Language is C#, web framework is ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: I do this same thing on my site, I just have a REST endpoint that is pinged via StatusCake.com every "X" seconds/minutes/hours/etc.

Comment: An external trigger is best. IIS might end up unloading your app if it's idle long enough. If you explain more about the DB query, people might be able to provide better advice. If this is an attempt to refresh a cache for instance, you're better off just checking if the cache is more than 10 minutes old before doing the query.

Comment: @itsme86 its a query that checks the status of two attributes and if both conditions are met It will delete a record

Comment: I'd probably just create a SQL job or scheduled task to do that.

Comment: @itsme86 how do you set one up?

Comment: One what? I mentioned two different things. Just google them.

Comment: sounds like it'd be easiest to do it as a sql job. there are lots of tutorials for setting them up and it's simple as SSMS includes a wizard to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using **CacheItemRemovedCallback**

in your `Global.asax` file add this lines at the end of your `Application_Start()`

```
if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache["cacheKey"]) return;

HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("cacheKey", "cacheValue", null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));
```

This will create new cache item that will trigger after 10 minutes

add the following method in `Global.asax`

```
public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
     //Your code here, call database procedures ...
     HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("cacheKey", "cacheValue", null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));
}
```

What happens here is that you are creating new cache and remove it after 10 minutes, when removing the cache the event `CacheItemRemovedCallback` is called so you can do your work and then create new cache that will be removed in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at HangFire https://www.hangfire.io/ for creating background processing jobs.